# inserting excel data into SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to insert excel data using Data flow task, Excel source to OLE DB Destination, my col names in the Excel file are in the following order

EmpId
Empname
Dept
Sal
StartDate
EndDate
EmpType

My question is do I need to define them in the same order as they are in the excel sheet or for e.g what if they are in the following order where StartDate preceeds Sal would it cause issues ?

EmpId
Empname
Dept
StartDate
Sal
EndDate
EmpType

As i'm getting the following errors when trying to run this package:

[Excel Source [37]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 2" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.

Error: There were errors during task validation.

Comment: The column headings in Excel would not make any difference to the SSIS connection unless you are using a specific "SELECT" statement. Somethings to check as these have tripped me up in the past: Is the Excel file password protected? Does you SSIS have read access to the Excel file location? Ids the Excel file already open?

Comment: I'm getting this error now recently, although I made sure my excel file is closed 

  
[Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 2"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".

Comment: As @MiguelH mentioned you need to check the user who is executing the `SSIS` package have requisite permission to open/read/write the Excel file.